# Cursor points to bottom when a zip file is opened with vim

Tags: vim, zip, vimrc

I am trying to open a `.zip` file via `vim`. By default the cursor points to the bottom of the file once it opens. How can I bring the cursor to the beginning of the file as soon as I open a `zip` file?

How can I change the default behavior of the `vim` to point it to the beginning of the file as soon as I open a `*.zip` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.zip :0
```

From the [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufEnter):

> ```
>                           *BufEnter*
> BufEnter      After entering a buffer.  Useful for setting
>               options for a file type.  Also executed when
>               starting to edit a buffer, after the
>               BufReadPost autocommands.
> ```

After entering the zip file, `:0` should be executed (goto line 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gg` or `:0` to go to the beginning of the file.

**from `:h gg`**

```
<C-Home>    or                  *gg* *<C-Home>*
gg          Goto line [count], default first line, on the first
            non-blank character |linewise|.  If 'startofline' not
            set, keep the same column.
```

Comment: yeah :) I know that. My question is how can I change the default behavior of the vim to point it to the beginning of the file as soon as I open a zip file

Comment: You can try starting vim without any plugins using `vim -u NONE`. I don't observe the behavior you are seeing.